# regex how to match only the first occurrence behind

Tags: regex

I want to match every occurrence of a string beginning with `al` and ending with a word ending in `i`.

Below is the string

```
al al spettatori
```

the problem is that in this string I have 2 `al` but I want to match only the one before the word ending with `i`.

The regex `/ al .*i` matches all the string.
I want to match only the string beginning from the last `al`:

`al spettatori`

but with my regexp it matches all the string from the beginning.
And still I want to use the greedy because it's a larger text than the example and I want to match every occurrence of a string beginning with `al` and ending with a word ending in `i`.

Comment: What types of regexes/programs do you use? perl, java, python, grep, sed, ...

Comment: If you want greedy, will you also match "al lorem ipsum ... ... ... delori" is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex

```
al(?!.*al).*i
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/8vQaYp/1)

Comment: Thank you Marvel, this was what I was looking for.